# How to enable Camel-Cased Code IntelliSense in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp

There is a good example in some languages or extensions, that I just input the first letters of some words of the control's name or function's name, the code IntelliSense tool will show up all the candidates which including the words that starting with those letter.

Example for the `NavigationViewItem`, if I input `nvi`, code intelligence tool may show up:

```
 1. NavigationViewItem
 2. NavigationViewItemOtherCandidate
 3. ThisIsNavigationViewItemToo
```

I tried many times in Visual Studio 2019/2022. It seems this function is not enabled by default. Or, this function doesn't exist in XAML?

Thanks for sharing your experience.

Comment: this is not a question... what do you want to know...?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is extensions like [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper), but it's **not** free. Then it is also much more than just intelligence suggestions.

Comment: @DenisSchaf how to say? why that is not a question?

Comment: with the changed title its quite clear, thank you